# Is there a way to resize all the pages of a PDF to one size in Python?

Tags: python, pdf

Essentially, I'm looking to resize all of the pdf pages in a document to be the same size as the first page (or any set dimensions i.e. A4). This is because it's causing issues for mapping coordinates on a frontend UI I am developing. The result I am hoping for is, that if for example, I have a PDF document with a landscape page, this will be mapped onto an A4 page and take up half the new page. Could anyone point me to any resources or code that might help me do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

**disclaimer** I am the author of `borb`, the library used in this answer.
**second disclaimer**: It's doable, but not easy.

You can use `borb` to read the PDF. That is the easy part.

```py
import typing
from borb.pdf.document.document import Document
from borb.pdf.pdf import PDF


def main():

    # read the Document
    doc: typing.Optional[Document] = None
    with open("output.pdf", "rb") as in_file_handle:
        doc = PDF.loads(in_file_handle)

    # check whether we have read a Document
    assert doc is not None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now that you have a representation of the `Document`, you need to obtain the size of the first `Page`.

```py
pi: PageInfo = doc.get_page(0).get_page_info()
w: Decimal = pi.get_width() or Decimal(0)
h: Decimal = pi.get_height() or Decimal(0)
```

Now, in every `Page` (except the first one) you need to update the content stream. The content stream is a sequence of postscript operators that actually renders the content in the PDF.

Luckily for you, there is a command to change the entire coordinate-system of the `Page` you are working on. This concept is called the transformation matrix.
Every operation will first change its x/y coordinates by applying this 3x3 transformation matrix.

Conversely, by modifying that matrix you are able to scale/translate/rotate all the content inside the `Page`.

The matrix has this form:

```
[[ a b 0 ]
 [ c d 0 ]
 [ e f 1 ]]
```

The third column is always [0 0 1], so it is not needed.
The `Tm` command takes 6 arguments (the remaining values) and sets the corresponding values in the transformation matrix.

So you'd need to do something like this:

```py
content_stream = page["Contents"]
instructions: bytes = b"a b c d e f Tm\n" + content_stream["DecodedBytes"]
content_stream[Name("DecodedBytes")] += instructions.encode("latin1")
content_stream[Name("Bytes")] = zlib.compress(content_stream["DecodedBytes"], 9)
content_stream[Name("Length")] = bDecimal(len(content_stream["Bytes"]))
```